# PL/SQL cursor to find all classes that have more than two students whose test scores are above 90% of the average scores of their classrooms?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am having problems working to get the right value for the number of students. I need to use cursors and the ouput of my program should look like this... I am looking to get led into the right direction where to go from here as I am a little confused. Thanks!

```
Class Name    Number of Students
=================================
Biology                        6
Calc                           3
German                         5
```

Here is my current code:

```
DECLARE
        CURSOR c_1 IS
            SELECT c.class_name, AVG(s.grade)
            FROM   class c, student s
                WHERE  c.class_id = s.class_id
            GROUP BY class_name
                ORDER BY class_name;

        grade_rec c_1%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(('Class Name') || '    ' || ('NUMBER OF Students'));
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('--------------------------------------');
      FOR grade_rec IN c_1 LOOP
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rpad(grade_rec.class_name, 15) || 
        '             ' || lpad(grade_rec.avg_grade, 10));
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Hint.. you want to know the number of students.  Try COUNTing them instead of AVGing their grades.  You will also probably want to give that column a column alias so you can easily reference it in your FOR loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky. But you can use HAVING to compare against a group by result.

Your select gives you the average by class. Now you need to count the number of students of a class that have a higher score then the average.

```
    select class_name, count(*) from student s2, 
        (SELECT c.class_name, class_id, AVG(s.grade) avgg
        FROM   class c, student s
            WHERE  c.class_id = s.class_id
        GROUP BY class_name, class_id) avg
      where avg.class_id = s2.class_id
        and s2.grade > avg.avgg  
    group by class_name
    having count(*) > 2
```

I have not tested it but it creates a subquery with average by class. Then you join the students again but only those with a higher then average grade. Finally you use the `having` clause to compare the count.